# Why GRANT EXECUTE ON Stored Procedure required every time?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

1. Create a stored procedure with user1 and grant execute to user2.

   ```
   login with user1

   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEL_ROWS (arg IN VARCHAR2 )  AS
   BEGIN
       //delete rows
   END DEL_ROWS;

   GRANT EXECUTE ON DEL_ROWS TO USER2;

   logout user1
   ```
2. Execute stored procedure with user2. It successfully deletes the rows.

   ```
   login user2

   DEL_ROWS('arg');

   //success

   logout user2
   ```
3. Insert some rows into the table

   ```
    login user1
    insert some rows in the table
    logout user1
   ```
4. Execute stored procedure with user2 again. This time, does not delete rows.

   ```
   login user2
   DEL_ROWS('arg');

   //does not delete rows
   ```
5. If I assign the GRANT EXECUTE again, it deletes the rows.

Is there anything I am missing while granting execute permission ?

Comment: In step 4, when it "does not delete rows", does it throw an error? Also, you might want to modify `DEL_ROWS` to write a line such as "DEL_ROWS called" to DBMS_OUTPUT - that way you can verify that the procedure was called.

Comment: The question assumes a premise which is not true. You don't need to re-grant the permission, but in your particular test case it has a side effect that causes the script to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suspicion is that you're not committing the transaction when you insert rows in step 3.

When you call GRANT EXECUTE from user 1 in step 5, that counts as a DDL. DDL's automatically commit the transaction after finishing, so it may be that the row insertion DML only gets committed at that point.

Try running the `commit;` command after inserting rows in step 3 as user 1 (if you aren't already). Also, try a `select count(*) from table;` query in step 4 as user 2 to see if user 2 actually sees any rows that it could delete.